# R stringr and str_extract_all: capturing contractions

Tags: regex, r, tokenize

I am doing a bit of NLP with R and am using the [stringr package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/index.html) to tokenize some text.

I would like be able to capture contractions, for example, **won't** so that it is tokenized into **"wo"** and **"n't"**.

Here is a sample of what I've got:

```
library(stringr)

s = "won't you buy my raspberries?"

foo = str_extract_all(s, "(n|t)|[[:punct:]]" )          # captures the contraction OK...
foo[[1]]
>[1] "n't" "?"  

foo = str_extract_all(s, "(n|t)|\\w+|[[:punct:]]" )       # gets all words, 
                                                  # but splits the contraction! 
foo[[1]]
>[1] "won"  "'"  "t"  "you"  "buy"  "my"  "raspberries"  "?"
```

I am trying to tokenize the above sentence into **"wo"**, **"n't"**, **"you"**, **"buy"**, **"my"**, **"raspberries"**,  **"?"**.

I am not too sure if I can do this with the [default, extended regular expressions](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html), or if I need to figure out some way to do this a Perl-like pattern.

Does anyone out there know of a way to do tokenization as described above with the  [stringr package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/index.html)?

**EDIT**
TO clarify, I am interested in [Treebank tokenization](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~treebank/tokenization.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this through lookaheads which was supported by  PCRE library.

```
> s = "won't you buy my raspberries?"
> s
[1] "won't you buy my raspberries?"
> m <- gregexpr("\\w+(?=n[[:punct:]]t)|n?[[:punct:]]t?|\\w+", s, perl=TRUE)
> regmatches(s, m)
[[1]]
[1] "wo"          "n't"         "you"         "buy"         "my"         
[6] "raspberries" "?"
```

OR

```
> m <- gregexpr("\\w+(?=\\w[[:punct:]]\\w)|\\w?[[:punct:]]\\w?|\\w+", s, perl=TRUE)
> regmatches(s, m)
[[1]]
[1] "wo"          "n't"         "you"         "buy"         "my"         
[6] "raspberries" "?"
```

OR

Through `stringr` library,

```
> s <- "won't you buy my raspberries?"
> str_extract_all(s, perl("\\w+(?=\\w[[:punct:]]\\w)|\\w?[[:punct:]]\\w?|\\w+") )[[1]]
[1] "wo"          "n't"         "you"         "buy"         "my"         
[6] "raspberries" "?"
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, @Avinash. Would there be any advantages to choosing the base gregexpr & regmatches approach versus the stringr approach?

Answer (score 2):

You could try the `perl` wrapper function when working with `stringr` package functions.

```
s <- "won't you buy my raspberries?"
pattern <- "(?=[a-z]'[a-z])|(\\s+)|(?=[!?.])"
library(stringr)
str_split(s, perl(pattern))[[1]]
# [1] "wo"          "n't"         "you"         "buy"         "my"         
# [6] "raspberries" "?"
```

There are also other wrappers such as `fixed` and `ignore.case`

Comment: Thanks for the response, @Richard. I will have a closer look at the wrapper functions you mentioned.